# Override Material UI expansion panel when it is expanded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, frontend

Is it possible to override the expansion panel summary height when it is expanded? To be more specific, i want to delete the min-height property and have the summary panel with a height of 40px instead of 64px (deafult value). I tried to apply a change to the min-height in the root component when it is exapanded.
Edit: also here is the sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-forked-3ujf6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

The code I am using is the same as the following:

```js
const styles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%"
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(15),
    fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
  },
  expansionPanel: {
    minHeight: "40px",
    "&$expanded": {
      minHeight: "40px"
    }
  }
});

function SimpleExpansionPanel(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <ExpansionPanel>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary
          classes={{ root: classes.expansionPanel }}
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        >
          <Typography className={classes.heading}>Expansion Panel 1</Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
        <ExpansionPanelDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelDetails>
      </ExpansionPanel>
      <ExpansionPanel>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
          <Typography className={classes.heading}>Expansion Panel 2</Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
        <ExpansionPanelDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelDetails>
      </ExpansionPanel>
      <ExpansionPanel disabled>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
          <Typography className={classes.heading}>
            Disabled Expansion Panel
          </Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
      </ExpansionPanel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The property i want to override/delete:

[image]

The example picture with the size I want to override:

[image]

I need the Summary panel to have 40px height.

Answer (score 1):

Material-UI itself has already a css api called `expanded` ( [link here](https://material-ui.com/api/expansion-panel-summary/#css) ), so you can just use it to override the style like this

```
<ExpansionPanelSummary
    classes={{ expanded: classes.expansionPanel }}
    ...
>
```

and you don't need `&$` that part.

Comment: when I tried to apply the style to the expanded with the same minHeight at 40px, the size increased from 64px to 80px which is a bit strange.

Comment: i still can't get it to shrink, I edited my post and posted a sanbox with the code. Could you try it there please?

Comment: @NunoOliveira Yeah, I see that, looks like it doesn't applied to the pseudo class, probably  a bug.

Comment: It is strange, i've been fighting with it for hours now and I don't seem to find the solution. It never overrides the property .MuiExpansionPanelSummary-root.Mui-expanded leaving me stuck with 64px @ChrisSu

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles =  makeStyles((theme) => ({
  overrideExpendedHeight: {
    minHeight: '40px',
  }
}));

function SimpleExpansionPanel(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  const muiClasses = useStyles();
  
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <ExpansionPanel classes={{ expanded: muiClasses.overrideExpendedHeight }}>
        ...
      </ExpansionPanel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Try this way for best practice with MUI.

Comment: Still can't reduce the size with that property. I tried it directly in the Expansion Panel but it i«still has 64px size

Comment: you need to make style object with `import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';` . I update my snippet already.

Comment: i still can't get it to shrink, I edited my post and posted a sanbox with the code. Could you  try it there please?

Comment: check this sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-3ujf6?from-embed=&file=/demo.js

Comment: Was there any change to the previous code?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-6ish5?file=/demo.js

Comment: I haven't noticed any differences

Comment: it did change the min-height, however , the property .MuiExpansionPanelSummary-root.Mui-expanded is still 64px, when i need it to be 40px. If you inspect in chrome like i did in the picture in the question, you can see it at 64px @Sinh

Comment: you don't see my comment in demo.js?

Comment: I saw your comments, and as I said, the 64px in the property .MuiExpansionPanelSummary-root.Mui-expanded still remain

Comment: ahh you want it on `MuiExpansionPanelSummary ` right?

Comment: use classes props that I use on `MuiExpansionPanel` to `MuiExpansionPanelSummary`

`<ExpansionPanelSummary classes={{ expanded: muiClasses.overrideExpendedHeight }} expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>`

Comment: If you look closely, in the previous code i did, there is a property like that in the ExpansionPanelSummary. ```<ExpansionPanelSummary
          classes={{ root: classes.expansionPanel }}
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        >``` and it did not work

Comment: yes I see, but like I comment we need to use style MUI makeStyles for style object.

Comment: I have change it to the makestyles as you said, but the result is still the same. I tried it in the sandbox link you sent.

Comment: than add `!important` to `const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  overrideExpendedHeight: {
    minHeight: "40px !important"
  }
}));`